# The derivative of x' with respect to x

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I'm trying to get back into maths after a couple of years out.

Looking at the opening chapter of a text book on Nonlinear Ordinary Differential Equations (the context is somewhat irrelevant) I've found an equation that I cannot make sense of:

$\ddot{x} = \frac{\mathrm d \dot{x}}{\mathrm d t} = \frac{\mathrm d \dot{{x}}}{\mathrm d x} \frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t} = 
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} (\frac{1}{2} \dot{x}^2)$

I undertand it using the chain rule, and it's clear that one of the $\dot{x}$'s comes from the $\frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t}$. However what I can't understand is how $\frac{\mathrm d \dot{x}}{\mathrm d x}$ becomes $\frac{1}{2} \dot{x}$.

I realise this is probably something obvious, but like I say, it's been a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to take into account the $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}$ in front of the bracket. Using the product rule on the last expression, we get
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} \left(\frac{1}{2} \dot{x}^2\right) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} \left( \dot{x}^2\right) \\
= \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\mathrm d\dot x}{\mathrm d x} \dot{x} + \dot x\frac{\mathrm d\dot x}{\mathrm d x}\right)\\
= \frac{\mathrm d\dot x}{\mathrm d x} \dot{x} = \frac{\mathrm d\dot x}{\mathrm d x} \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm d t}
$$
Your textbook just did this in reverse.

Comment: Eurgh, how did I miss that. I'm rubbish at spotting these things.

Comment: I find that many of these "tricks" used in different fields of mathematics are easier to follow in reverse. That direction, it's simple. The reason we call them tricks is that they're not as easy to discover when going the other direciton. Standard factorisations of polynomials is another example, with $x^2 + 2xy + y^2 = (x+y)^2$ at the forefront.